# Alphabetical app list on xperia Z1 compact

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, launcher, app-drawer, softkey

An earlier Lollipop ROM on my Xperia Z1 compact had the option to sort the apps alphabetically in a very nice way: Apps were put in a matrix with one row per letter, and the apps sorted alphabetically in subsequent columns.

Now I have CyanogenMod 12.1 which is great, but I cannot find the setting that would bring back this app ordering.

I have forgotten how to restore this wonderful way to get to the apps. Does anyone know whether this is a special launcher, app or theme?

(the [apus](http://www.lowfatgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/apus-launcher-find-apps.jpg) and [aviate](http://cdn.nirmaltv.com/images/Aviate-Launcher-5.png) launchers seem to have similar functionality, but I have never installed those and their names don't sound familiar)

Some posts describe a route via the 'menu' button in the app drawer, but the only softkeys I have are `back`, `home` and `window list`.

Could it be a Cyanogenmod / Lollipop feature that is just really hard to find?

Comment: If you're open to [alternative launchers/homescreens](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher), at least *Apex* and *Nova* offer this (including the possibility to "hide unwanted apps" from the list).

Comment: it is a feature of the launcher in cyanogenmod 12.1(android 5.1) . It should be by default but when u see launcher settings, u can toggle app drawer view to old style matrix. Long press on the home screen and check launcher settings / app drawer settings.

Comment: Thanks! Is that Trebuchet then? I have installed Google Apps (the micro version) and selected Google Now. But its settings are 'Accounts & privacy', 'Search language', 'Voice', 'Phone search' and 'Now cards'. I switched to Google Now because I could not find it on Trebuchet either though.

Comment: That works brilliantly @BharatG ! I cannot accept your comment as an answer but I up-voted it. Now that I have re-installed Trebuchet (had deleted it after choosing Google Now) and switched from `paged` to `vertical` it looks exactly the way I wanted it to.

Comment: I still can't find the setting on OnePlus 3 (cyanogen)

Comment: Do you use Trebuchet as the launcher?